# Using geodatabase for processing 7200 polylines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, database, line

I have 7200 lines and I want to divide each of them every 100 meters and take the coordinates of points from them. For that task should I create a geodatabase and put them in there?

I am totally newbie with geodatabases and I don't have much time. Any good tutorial? Because then I will have to do that with python also.

Has the geodatabase the capacity for that task?

I have ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: 7.2k lines isn't worth worrying about relative performance of data storage formats, especially since this will be a full table scan query.

Comment: Just to clarify - a File Geodatabase or Enterprise Geodatabase sitting on top of a RDMS (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres)? What format is your data in now?

Comment: What format what do you mean? I will use a script in pytohn to extract these lines and i want them to be imported in an ArcSDE geodatabase. I don't know if it helped

Comment: If performance is an issue why not load your data to an in_memory workspace, do your processing then write out from that?  But as @Vince says 7.2k is not particularly large.

Comment: Hornybydd an in_memory workspace can be used to continue with my procession; exporting pnts, tables from these polylines etc and finally save them, so as to use them whenever i want;

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, for reasons other than performance. In my experience using a File geodatabase (if you're not talking about an enterprise DB) makes things a little easier to handle in Arc. Shapefiles have some limitations that you could run in to later. geodatabases might help you keep things organized and contained. Exporting from a FileGDB with Arc is simple, so if you need it in another format later it's not a big deal.

There is a tool you can [run with arcpy for](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000q0000000) creating geodatabase, and tools adding data etc.

I would say that there are a few ways you could skin this cat, but I would personally use a FileGDB unless you have a specific reason not to (for example, if you will using systems other than Arc)

Comment: Tangar thank you very much for your repsonse. No i don't have other system. It is just that i want to extract for every one of them points per 100 meter, then calculate their coorindnates, and finally do some math with them, with arcpy all these. So i thought that i cannot have 7200 shp in my Table of Contents. That's all. I fi want to use a file geodatabase i ll use it only to add my polylines and everything else i ll do next or the whole procedure i have done until now also; Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Well, in that kind of tasks I always prefer to export to dxf the shape file and use AutoCad to divide the lines, that software have a lot of tools you can use and for me is more simple; after that, I import the DWG file to SHAPE... but it always depends on the data base, If the database is big maybe is better to look for another way to do it!!!